# Care/Care about

Tags: idiomatic-language, word-in-context

Psychiatrist: As a psychiatrist it can be depressing listening to clients' problems all day, but that's the job.

Person: **So is it just a job to you or do you actually care?**

Psychiatrist: I care.

- Is the question natural and meaningful?
- Is "care" enough? Is it clear what is meant by it? Or should I add something to it "care about…"?

Comment: Your two conversants could spend the rest of the day discussing exactly what ***to care*** might mean in the context of people working in ***the caring professions***. This isn't really a question about "English" - it's about how people in those kinds of jobs maintain some kind of meaningful work/life "balance".

Comment: Is this question about something  you are writing? The answer depends on what you are trying to say. Also, the previous question was asked with the same ambiguity: "Do you actually care?". If that question was accepted as is, "I care." is an acceptable answer.

Comment: There's usually a difference between saying a nurse cares ***for*** patients or cares ***about*** them (which there might not have been, a century or two ago). But is that actually what this question is about?

Comment: "So is it just a job to you or do you actually care about your clients?" Is this natural and meaningful to ask? Would "genuinely" be better than "actually"?

Comment: Better in what sense? It's your sentence. What are you trying to say?

Comment: I know they're slightly different, but I just want to know if it seems a more natural choice of word in the context.

Comment: It seems to me that you could use "genuinely", "actually", "really', "in fact", or "truly" with about the same meaning.

Comment: If you are open to other suggestions, you might start your sentence with the phrase "For a psychiatrist..." It would link to what follows a little better.

Comment: I am. Thank you.

Comment: The question is clear and meaningful. "Care" is enough that we understand what it means in the context.

Answer (score 0):

As written it's entirely natural in moderately formal spoken English.

The difference between *care* and *care about* ("...do you actually care about it?") in this context would be a subtle one. In my opinion *care* fits better because its opposite is a slightly more generalized apathy. One can easily imagine a character saying, "Nowadays psychiatry is just a job to me. I don't care any more." It just sounds more jaded and burned out than, "I don't care about it any more," which implies overall emotional health and just a simple loss of interest.