# "But maybe you just don't?"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, idiomatic-language

*You could at least have called her, let her know that you care. **But maybe you just don't?***

Is the highlighted part completely natural in continuation to the rest to mean *but maybe you just don't care?* or would you rephrase it?

Comment: It's natural enough, if spoken by actors who have understood it. Maybe for written text, you should repeat the word "care" at the end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Care/Care about](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/246370/care-care-about)

Comment: I don't understand the distinction between this question and the previous one you had asked. (The fact that this is a negation doesn't make it different, as far as I can tell.)

Answer (score 2):

This is completely natural in neutral-register spoken English. It's also completely natural and slightly informal in written English (e.g. emailing an acquaintance).

You are correct; *don't* stands in for *don't care*.

For comparison:

- I would like to learn Chinese; I'm afraid I just can't.
- I asked him to stop by the supermarket, but he probably [just] won't.

More subtly:

- The prosecutor accused her of embezzling funds, but she claimed she didn't [or hadn't].

Comment: Not sure myself, but wouldn't it be better to use "wasn't" or "hadn't been" in the last sentence? You wouldn't say, "She didn't/hadn't embezzling funds".

Comment: @MicahWindsor It's not necessarily a direct substitution -- *she claimed the didn't* here means *she claimed she didn't embezzle funds*. Look at it this way: if the prosecutor said *You embezzled funds,* it would be perfect natural for the accused to respond *I did not!* even though you would never say *I did not embezzled funds.*

Comment: @Caleb, the change from "I did not embezzled funds" to "I did not embezzle funds" is merely conjugation of the verb. It's still pretty much direct substitution, and it works.

Comment: I hesitated on that last example because, although my formulation off the top of my head was "didn't," it actually is slightly more tense-consistent to say "hadn't" (implying a past perfect). Native speakers, at least in the US, tend to make nonstandard use of past perfect, conditional perfect, etc. So "didn't" is fine in informal speech.